# Mergin dataframes on different index levels

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dfs, `df_1`:

```
                            col_1       col_2
index_1     index_2
abc         a_1             10          20
            a_2             15          15
            c_2             48          74
def         a_1             10          15
            b_2             1           1
```

And `df_2`:

```
id          value
abc         value_abc
def         value_def
a_1         value_a_1
a_2         value_a_2
b_2         value_b_2
c_2         value_c_2
```

I am trying to merge the values to the indexes like so:

```
                            col_1       col_2       value_index_1           value_index_2
index_1     index_2
abc         a_1             10          20          value_abc               value_a_1
            a_2             15          15                                  value_a_2
            c_2             48          74                                  value_c_2
def         a_1             10          15          value_def               value_a_1
            b_2             1           1                                   value_c_2
```

So both `index_1` and `index_2` is a `id` field in `df_2` and I am trying to add the `value` columns as 2 different columns in the original `df_1`.

I tried:

```
df_1.merge(df_2, left_on = 'index_1', right_on ='id', how = 'left', left_index=True)
```

But this removes the visibility of `index_2` for some reason. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Could you provide the code needed to create those two data frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rename` by `Series` from `df_2`, convert to `DataFrame`, reaasign default index and append to original:

```
df = df_1.join(df_1.rename(df_2['value']).index.to_frame().set_index(df_1.index))
print (df)
                 col_1  col_2    index_1    index_2
index_1 index_2                                    
abc     a_1         10     20  value_abc  value_a_1
        a_2         15     15  value_abc  value_a_2
        c_2         48     74  value_abc  value_c_2
def     a_1         10     15  value_def  value_a_1
        b_2          1      1  value_def  value_b_2
```

Reason why values are repeated is possible find in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object):

> We’ve “sparsified” the higher levels of the indexes to make the console output a bit easier on the eyes. Note that how the index is displayed can be controlled using the multi_sparse option in pandas.set_options():

```
with pd.option_context("display.multi_sparse", False):
    df
```

Comment: Hm, I can't seem to get this work, instead I get `index_1     index_2` added as a columns to `df_1` and not the `value` column. Does it change that my `df_2` actually has more columns and the `id` and `value` columns are not the 1st and 2nd columns but in the middle of my real `df`?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - then change `df_2['value']` to `df_2.set_index('id')['value']`